# Reading 2d array from file in Python

Tags: python

The following code fills a 2d array (grid) with random numbers(0 or 1):

```
def create_initial_grid(rows, cols):

grid = []
for row in range(rows):
    grid_rows = []
    for col in range(cols):

        if random.randint(0, 7) == 0:
            grid_rows += [1]
        else:
            grid_rows += [0]

    grid += [grid_rows]
return grid
```

I want to fill the grid from a text file that looks like this:

```
7
0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,1,0,1,0,0
0,0,1,1,1,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Comment: To read a row, you could simply do `row.split(',')`.

Comment: I removed your image and wrote it as text. I did this for you, because you are new, but you should do that yourself in the future. See [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other option is to use [numpy.loadtxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) to read `.txt` (since you are use the `array` and `matrix` format):

```
data = np.loadtxt("text.txt", delimiter=",",dtype=int , skiprows=1) 
print(data)
```

> Out:
>
> ```
> [[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
>  [0 0 1 0 1 0 0]
>  [0 0 1 1 1 0 0]
>  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
>  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
>  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
>  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
> ```
>
> Note:
>
> `skiprows=1` # parameter for skipping the first line when reading from
>   the file.
>
> `dtype=int` parameter for reading in the `int` format (default is
>   `float`)

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file, with:

```
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    next(f)  # skip the first line
    data = [list(map(int, line.strip().split(','))) for line in f]
```

Here `next(..)` will move the cursor to the next line, since the first here contains a `7`.

If there is data *after* the lines, we might want to prevent reading that, and use:

```
from itertools import islice

with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    n = int(next(f))  # skip the first line
    data = [list(map(int, line.strip().split(','))) for line in islice(f, n)]
```

For both file fragments here, the result is:

```
>>> data
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
filesname = "t.txt"

with open(filesname) as f:
    lines = f.read().split()

n = lines[0]
data_lines = lines[1:]

data = [map(int, row.split(",")) for row in data_lines]

print(data)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This won't work in Python 3.x where `map` is a lazy iterator.